# android bluetooth get Baud rate

Tags: android, bluetooth, baud-rate

Hi currently working on a project that is working over bluetooth.

The device that I talk to has a couple of different modes.
Each of these modes uses a different baud rate.

I've used the bluetooth chat example for this project.

My problem is as follows

Each of the returns for these devices sends back different end strings. ("\r\n" , "\r")

I want to be able to tell what mode the device is in. The best way I can think of is to find what baud rate the device is currently in to do so. Is there some way of finding the information from the connection?